# How to target class and span text

Tags: css

I have this link

```
<a class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a>
```

I want to hide the the link all together. That link in particular has text

```
<span>Home</span>
```

And class `level-top`.

I have **[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs6m87mL/1/)**

How do I hide the link?.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I hide the link?" It's hidden in your fiddle already.

Comment: I want to use the span text to target. Currently, i hide via the css class only.

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the link with class `level-top` and that contains the text `Home` you could use:

```js
$('a.level-top:contains("Home")').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a>
<br/>
<a class="level-top"><span>Different text</span></a>
<br/>
<a><span>Home without class</span></a>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that with just css,the jquery also does work.

Comment: Sorry, there no CSS selector for elements containing certain text :(

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you would like to hide the home link only, why not give it an id of 'home' and then target it to hide?

`<a id="home" class="level-top"><span>Home</span></a>`

then

```
#home {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to condition it so that it should not show on certain pages, you could use jQuery for this. Let’s say the menu id was 'menu':

```
$('#menu #home').hide();
```

You'd have to obviously wrap this in a condition which knows that it is the homepage, for example:

```
if($('body').hasClass('home') {
  $('#menu #home').hide();
}
```

Some CMSes such as WordPress should provide this. If you are using static HTML, you can add the 'home' class yourself.

Comment: I will try using pseudo classes and try and see if it can get fixed.